# Detect exception while deserializing in Servicestack's JsConfig

Tags: c#, servicestack, json-deserialization

My customer want to receive and send the DateTime Objects my wonderful ServiceStack service formatted as *'yyyyMMdd'*.

I would like to notify to the client that whenever the format is not correct. As the framework functions like **ParseExact** throw the FormatException i would like to catch them somehow;

Here's my code

```
        JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = dt =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt))
                return null;

            return DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        };
```

I think that probably, in case of FormatException error the service should just go on and give the freedom to the Service to choose wheter or not noticing the missing value; but i would like to know if there is a way to detect them.

Best regards, and Merry holydays

Comment: There is no such a thing as; a `DateTime` with `yyyyMMdd` format. I think your customer sends you `string` with `yyyyMMdd` format. I'm not familiar with `ServiceStack` and JSON serialization but, which line you get this `FormatException`?

Comment: I've edited the code. ParseExact throws the exception, but this is irrelevant as it doesn't depend on the Exception type.
BTW: with the actual update, you can see that THERE is a way to format and receive the *yyyyMMdd* format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the condensed `yyyyMMdd` date format was just added so ServiceStack's Json Serializer can now handle dates like `20001213`, e.g:

```
var date = "20001213".FromJson<DateTime>(); // new DateTime(2000, 12, 13)
```

There's also a new `DateTimeSerializer.OnParseErrorFn` where you can handle invalid date formats, e.g:

```
DateTimeSerializer.OnParseErrorFn = (str, ex) =>
    DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date = "001213".FromJson<DateTime>();  // new DateTime(2000, 12, 13)
```

Both these changes are available from **v4.0.35+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).